# using css property to determine javascript (jquery) function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I am trying to use a css property via media query to determine which js (jquery) function to use (accordion/dialog box) and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help:

```
if ($(".small").css("float") == "left") {
    $(function() {
        $( "#Items" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
}else{
    $(function() {
        $( "#Items" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
        }); 
        $( ".blurb" ).click(function() {
            $( "#Items" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using anonymous functions here? Could use simple `if-else`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {
```

Is normally used to bind an anonymous function to happen when the page finished loading. I'm guessing by the time you're running this code the page has already loaded.

Remove that whole wrapper and just start doing what you want to do after the if { or else {

Asides from that the code looks okay.

```
if ($(".small").css("float") == "left") {
    $( "#Items" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });

} else {
    $( "#Items" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
    }
    }); 
    $( ".blurb" ).click(function() {
        $( "#Items" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(function(){})`, use simple `if-else` as:

```
if ($(".small").css("float") == "left") {
        $( "#Items" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
}else{
        $( "#Items" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
        }); 
        $( ".blurb" ).click(function() {
            $( "#Items" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = parseInt(window.innerWidth); // Find the width of the screen

    if (width <= 1024) {
        $("#dialog-one").dialog();
    }
    if (width >= 1024) {
        $("#dialog-two").dialog();
    }
});
```

Sometimes that may be kinda funky if you are resizing the browser and testing

In which case try adding or swapping

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

with / for

```
$(document).resize(function()
```

Hope it helps! 
I know it's saved me before!